# tsql group by get alphanumeric column value with maximum length

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, group-by, max

I have a sql view, let's call it `SampleView`, whose results have the following format.

```
Id (INT), NameA (VARVHAR(50)), NameB (VARCHAR(50)), ValueA (INT), ValueB (INT)
```

The result set of the view contains rows that may have the same `Id` or not. When there are two or more rows with the same Id, I would like to get something like the following

```
SELECT 
    Id,
    MAX(NameA),
    MAX(NameB),
    MAX(ValueA),
    MAX(ValueB)
FROM SampleView
GROUP BY Id
ORDER BY Id
```

Regarding the columns `Id`, `ValueA` and `ValueB` there isn't any problem. On the other hand using `MAX` for both `NameA` and `NameB` things are not as expected. After some googling and searching I realized that `MAX` has not the "expected" behavior for alphanumeric columns. Saying the expected, I mean using `MAX` in my case, it would be to return the value of `NameA` with the maximum number of characters, `MAX(LEN(NameA))`. I have to mention here that there ins't any possibility for `NameA` to have two values for the same `Id` with the same length. This might makes the problem more easy to be solved.

I use SQL Server 2012 and `TSQL`.

Have you any suggestion on how I could deal with this problem?

Thank you very much in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
       id,
       FIRST_VALUE(NameA) OVER (PARTITION BY id 
                                ORDER BY len(NameA) DESC) AS MaxNameA,
       MAX(ValueA) OVER (PARTITION BY id) AS MaxValueA,
       FIRST_VALUE(NameB) OVER (PARTITION BY id 
                                ORDER BY len(NameB) DESC) AS MaxNameB,
       MAX(ValueB) OVER (PARTITION BY id) AS MaxValueB      
FROM SampleView
```

[**Demo here**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/451426)

Comment: Thank you very much ! It is that I want :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use correlated queries like this:

```
SELECT 
    t.Id,
    (SELECT TOP 1 s.NameA FROM SampleView s
     WHERE s.id = t.id
     ORDER BY length(s.NameA) DESC) as NameA,
    (SELECT TOP 1 s.NameB FROM SampleView s
     WHERE s.id = t.id
     ORDER BY length(s.NameB) DESC) as NameB,
    MAX(t.ValueA),
    MAX(t.ValueB)
FROM SampleView t
GROUP BY t.Id
ORDER BY t.Id
```

Comment: My bad, I should had mentioned that I didn't want it a correlated query. However, since your answer is correct (+1) from me :)

Answer (score 0):

One possible variant is to use `ROW_NUMBER` twice:

```
WITH
CTE_NameA
AS
(
    SELECT
        Id,
        NameA,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY LEN(NameA) DESC) AS rnA
    FROM SampleView
)
,CTE_NameB
AS
(
    SELECT
        Id,
        NameB,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY LEN(NameB) DESC) AS rnB
    FROM SampleView
)
SELECT 
    Id,
    CTE_NameA.NameA,
    CTE_NameB.NameB,
    MAX(ValueA),
    MAX(ValueB)
FROM
    SampleView
    INNER JOIN CTE_NameA ON CTE_NameA.Id = SampleView.Id AND CTE_NameA.rnA = 1
    INNER JOIN CTE_NameB ON CTE_NameB.Id = SampleView.Id AND CTE_NameB.rnB = 1
GROUP BY Id
ORDER BY Id;
```

Comment: Thats seems like to much :S